# Modelling the coming and going of people in a mess, with social distancing, to get probability of a person finding a desirable seat.

Tags: mathematical-modeling, simulation

There is a room which has fixed spaces for people to sit and eat food (say benches). Each such space has a desirability rating depending upon a) Its location relative to the door and b) the number of occupied spaces around it at a particular time. Also, considering 1 person per space. So, the desirability of a space will be:
$$
D(i) = - \biggl(C_i + \sum_{k=0}^n {\operatorname{IsOccupied}(k) C_{i,k}} \biggr)
$$
Where $i$ is the selected space, $k$ are numbers denoting the rest of the spaces, $C_{i,k}$ is the steric effect constant on space $i$ due to spaces $k$ being occupied and $\operatorname{IsOccupied}(k)$ is a boolean function which gives $1$ as output when the space k is occupied and $0$ if not. Hence, $0$ being the highest desirability.

Now, consider people start coming in with a time interval $\lambda$ [Poisson distribution] and occupying spaces such that, the every person will choose the most desirable space. (In case of equal desirability, just choose one of those at random)

Now, every person, takes some time to eat food and leave: $\Delta t$~$N[\mu,\sigma^2]$;
Let $\mu=15minutes$ and $\sigma = 5 minutes$

If the mess starts at time $t_0$, considering these, can we find the probability of a person coming in at time $t_1 = $ some chosen time, to get a space with a desirability above a certain level (say $-0.5$)?

[Layout of 8 benches. Example simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SaJw.png)

Taking from the layout in the picture $n=8$. Following are the values of constants:

$
C_1=0.3;\space
C_2=0.2;\space
C_3=0.15;\space
C_4=0.8;\space
C_5=0.6;\space
C_6=0.2;\space
C_7=0;\space
C_8=0.15;\space
C_{1,2}=0.7=C_{2,1};\space
C_{1,4}=0.5=C_{4,1};\space
C_{1,5}=0.2=C_{5,1};\space
C_{2,5}=0.5=C_{5,2};\space
C_{2,3}=0.7=C_{3,2};\space
C_{3,5}=0.5=C_{5,3};\space
C_{6,4}=0.45=C_{4,6};\space
C_{6,7}=0.7=C_{7,6};\space
C_{7,5}=0.45=C_{5,7};\space
C_{7,4}=0.44=C_{4,7};\space
C_{7,8}=0.5=C_{8,7};\space
C_{8,5}=0.4=C_{5,8};\space
$
For all unspecified values: $C_{i,k}=0$

I looked for it in some simulation software, but could not see how to get the specific type of answer.
Any idea of what kind of path I might take to get to the answer is appreciated.

---

Edit: Did a quick  sanity check and realised there was no way to get a positive $D(i)$.

Comment: "steric effect constants"? What are these and how are they computed?

Comment: If you check out the illustration, you will see that the values of $C_i$ are dependent on the chance of people coming close to that specific space while going from the Door to the Food serving area. And $C_{i,k}$ are dependent on how close the person sitting in position i will feel if a person sits in position k. No of course I have just eye-balled it, but I have made sure that a person sitting on an adjacent space makes more difference than a person just passing through.
Also I forgot to tell earlier but $C_{i,k} = C_{k,i}$ for all i and k and if neither one is given then the constant is $0$